# apt-cache show specific dependencies

Tags: apt, apache2

It would appear that it specifies that the following dependencies are installed:

```
2.4.6-2ubuntu4
2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4
2.2.22-1ubuntu1
```

Why does the apache2 package consist of sub dependencies (apache2-bin) provided by dependencies (2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4, etc) that appear to be of different versions of apache?

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2

Specifies that the above packages are in fact disparate packages of disparate versions.

Is this just a peculiarity of the deployment of this backport?

apt-cache showpkg specifies:

```
2.4.6-2ubuntu4 - lsb-base (0 (null)) procps (0 (null)) perl (0 (null)) mime-support (0 (null)) apache2-bin (5 2.4.6-2ubuntu4) apache2-data (5 2.4.6-2ubuntu4) www-browser (0 (null)) apache2-doc (0 (null)) apache2-suexec-pristine (16 (null)) apache2-suexec-custom (0 (null)) ufw (0 (null)) apache2-utils (0 (null)) ssl-cert (0 (null)) apache2.2-common (0 (null)) apache2.2-common:i386 (0 (null)) apache2.2-common (0 (null)) apache2.2-common:i386 (0 (null)) apache2:i386 (0 (null)) 
2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4 - apache2-mpm-worker (21 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) apache2-mpm-prefork (21 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) apache2-mpm-event (21 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) apache2-mpm-itk (5 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) apache2.2-common (5 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) apache2:i386 (0 (null)) 
2.2.22-1ubuntu1 - apache2-mpm-worker (21 2.2.22-1ubuntu1) apache2-mpm-prefork (21 2.2.22-1ubuntu1) apache2-mpm-event (21 2.2.22-1ubuntu1) apache2-mpm-itk (5 2.2.22-1ubuntu1) apache2.2-common (5 2.2.22-1ubuntu1) apache2:i386 (0 (null))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the description of the package you will learn why:

`apt-cache show apache2`

> Description-en: Apache HTTP Server
>    The Apache Software Foundation's goal is to build a secure, efficient and
>    extensible HTTP server as standards-compliant open source software. The
>    result has long been the number one web server on the Internet.
>
> **This package contains the configuration files, init scripts and support
>    scripts. It does not install the actual apache2 binaries.**

On the other hand, maybe some of the packages you have installed that are not related to apache2 sources needs an specific version of apache, holding back the upgrade. Apache packages are upgraded and has the same blob version whenever they are built but in they doesn't need to have the same version to work (you can check using `apt-cache depends package`, through is recommendable to have the same version).

You may check with `apt-cache policy 'apache2*'` if your system really doesn't have the last version of all apache package installed and then check which of them are hold back.

Comment: I did read that and that refers to 2.4.6-2ubuntu4 and that only serves to illustrate the purpose of the question and the arising confusion. 2.4.6-2ubuntu4 in showpkg appears to specify that it contains packages, including apache2-bin and apache2-common (which is previously specified that it replaces). Hence the formulation of this question. Thanks for your help, I'm sorry but your answer is not productive.

Comment: @MetaChrome sorry but then your question is not clear, what is your confusion? All the packages are built in the repository with the same package version and are available, apache2 doesn't require all its packages to be an specific version to work, from your output it doesn't seems to be any problem, the behavior can happen with any package if another specify that it needs an specific version, you don't show the policy and reverse dependencies of the packages. Either edit your question and be more verbose about the confusion you have or I doubt anyone could be able to answer your doubts

Comment: Thank you for this elaboration. In your comment you appear to specify that this is explicitly caused by a reverse dependency. Which answers the question.